# Webpack Image Loader & Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Rails 6 and webpack to run react on front-end and am having issues getting images to appear on my react components.

I'm using Gulp tasks in conjunction with webpack to watch and compile the files. Here's what my task looks like:

```
function generateBundle(dev)
{
  log('bundling dev');
  return gulp.src([paths.js.boot])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(webpack_stream({
      watch: dev,
      mode: dev ? 'development' : 'production',
      entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/frontend/javascripts/boot.js'],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
              },
            ],
          },
        ]
      },
      devtool: dev ? "inline-source-map" : "source-map",
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      plugins: dev ? [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
            }
          })
        ] : [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
          })
        ]
    }, webpack))
    //.on('error', onError)
    .pipe(chmod(0o755))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts')));
}
```

I have an image I've placed in my `app/frontend/images/` directory and I can confirm that webpack is picking this image up and compiling it. Here's the gulp output:

```
[12:01:08] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/core_react/gulpfile.js
[12:01:08] Starting 'watch'...
[12:01:08] Starting 'watch-components'...
[12:01:08] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[12:01:08] Starting 'watch-components-for-application'...
[12:01:08] bundling dev
[12:01:12] Version: webpack 4.41.1
Built at: 2020-01-03 12:01:12
        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
PulseLogo.png  17.9 KiB          [emitted]
    bundle.js  7.44 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
[12:01:12] webpack is watching for changes
```

When I'm importing the image in a component, I receive a 406 error from Rails. Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PulseLogo from '../../images/PulseLogo.png';

class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return <img src={PulseLogo} />
  }
}
```

The console error I receive: `GET http://localhost:3000/PulseLogo.png 406 (Not Acceptable)`

The server log error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (DashboardController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["image/png"]
request.variant: []):
```

Here's my controllers:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

And my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users, {skip: :sessions, class_name: 'User' }

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]

    resources :users
  end

  get '*path', to: 'dashboard#index', constraints: ->(request) do
    !request.xhr?
  end
end
```

I understand that the Rails error implies I am not handling the request format of the image, but I can't seem to find how to fix this. Can anyone guide me as to the best way of handling this?

Thanks!